# How to implement Bag of words feature hashing in python?

Tags: python, hash, machine-learning, nlp

I'm trying to classify a few thousand documents, with a few lines each.  I've used regular bag of words before, but want to use the hashing trick this time, and I'm having trouble understanding the implementation.  There are around 8000 unique words in my data, so I figure 128*128 should be enough

I'm using mostly these sources:

http://blog.someben.com/2013/01/hashing-lang/
http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2008/HPL-2008-91R1.pdf

Here is my function to generatve feature vectors for each document:

```
import mmh3

def add_doc(text):
    text = str.split(text)
    d_input = dict()
    for word in text:
        hashed_token = mmh3.hash(word) % 127
        d_input[hashed_token] = d_input.setdefault(hashed_token, 0) + 1
    return(d_input)
```

Now I must be doing something wrong, or not understanding something somewhere, because there seem to be a huge amount of collisions.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you want to find 127 most common words in the text: [`collections.Counter(text.split()).most_common(127)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be modding the hash by % 127, that will only generate 127 possible outputs, where as you seem to want 128^2 possible outputs as per your 8000 unique words reasoning.

Comment: thanks, yes that line was in the loop, I must have pasted it wrong.  I just fixed the main post.